# Icons command line generator

Tags: linux, command-line, icons

Are there any command line utilities for Linux (or other Unix-like OS) which can:

- Generate an .ico file with multiple icons in it
- Do it from only 1 (*one*) png or jpeg image

For example:

```
% cool_icon_maker myimage_128x128.png file.ico
```

In `file.ico` there should automatically be all the icon sizes like 128x128, 64x64, 32x32, 16x16, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know all-in-one solution, but I know two pieces that can be brought together:

- [icoutils](http://www.nongnu.org/icoutils/) has `icotool`, which can create/extract .ico files.
- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) has `convert`, which can convert and resize the files to the desired sizes.

So, something like this will work (it may only work for files with ".png" extension):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Just pass the original .png image as the only parameter to this script.
SOURCE="$1"
BASE=`basename "${SOURCE}" .png`

convert "${SOURCE}" -thumbnail 16x16 "${BASE}_16.png"
convert "${SOURCE}" -thumbnail 32x32 "${BASE}_32.png"
convert "${SOURCE}" -thumbnail 48x48 "${BASE}_48.png"
convert "${SOURCE}" -thumbnail 64x64 "${BASE}_64.png"

icotool -c -o "${BASE}.ico" "${BASE}"_{16,32,48,64}.png

rm -f  "${BASE}"_{16,32,48,64}.png
```

It's damn ugly, I know. But it is simple to understand, and it works (I tested it!). Just be careful, as it will create temporary files on current directory, and later delete them.

Comment: Very old topic but I found this answer very useful and wanted to share this rewrite of your code: https://gist.github.com/lcuis/45a9ff2fc2bbe75986c918014b2af322

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is, but it probably would be a couple of lines script using "convert".